# How can I link to a image in google photos but download the file instead of opening it

Tags: html, force-download

I've realised that there are many ways to get a file saved on your computer or server root to download but I can not find a way on how to do it to a specific image in a google photos album.

```
<div class="the-content">
  <p><img class="b-lazy" id="portrait" src="https://image from google photos"  align="" width="300" height="103000" alt="about">
  <a href="https://photos.google.com/SAME IMAGE FROM GOOGLE PHOTOS ALBUM">
  <button>GET</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `a` element's `download` attribute should do what you're asking.

```
<a href="https://google.com/image/image.jpg" download>Download image.jpg</a>
or
<a href="https://google.com/image/image.jpg" download="rooster.jpg">Download image.jpg with the name rooster.jpg</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Yeah I have already tried that technique but it will not work with an image from google photos. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The issue is that it's a cross-origin resource; browsers protect their users from JavaScript downloading external files into their computers. I believe they still allow cross-origin image urls in img element as a source, so the trick would be to get the image from the img element after it's loaded. Still looking for a way to do this; stay tuned ;)

Comment: So I've been experimenting with using JS to build SVGs and canvases... With no luck yet, and I'm done for tonight. Do you have access to the web server and are you able to write custom endpoints? Because a simpler solution to my client-side JS is to use a download a element to send a request to your server for the image, have your server fetch it from Google, and serve it back to your user.